# Joining two sql tables where one join field is used multiple times

Tags: sql, database

I have an issue linking two tables, where 1 joining field is required multiple times.

The two tables are as follows:

**Venue_Location_Master**

- id
- location_name
- unid
- is_warehouse

**Bag_Dim**

- event_id
- Bag_type
- bag_id
- label_id
- created_date
- created_by_employee
- origin_location_id
- destination_location_id
- composition_id

The tables are joined on origin_location_id or destination_location_id to Venue_Location_Master.id

I'm trying to construct a query that returns:

- bag_id
- created_by_employee
- event_name
- origin_location_id
- Venue_Location_Master.location_name (origin_name)
- destination_location_id
- Venue_Location_Master.location_name (destination_name)

I've tried using a union, but that returns the required data, but across two rows (see below). Anyone have any suggestions?

```
SELECT [bag_id],
[created_date],
[created_by_employee],
[origin_location_id], 
ISNULL([venue_location_master].[location_name], 'NULL') AS [origin_location_name],   
[destination_location_id],
ISNULL([venue_location_master].[location_name], 'NULL') AS [destination_location_name]    
,ISNULL([event_master].[event_name], 'NULL') AS [event_name]  
FROM [variance_cash].[dbo].[Bag_Dim] 
LEFT JOIN [verteda_rts_v4].[dbo].[venue_location_master]  
ON [Bag_Dim].[destination_location_id] = [venue_location_master].[id]  
LEFT JOIN [verteda_rts_v4].[dbo].[event_master] 
ON [Bag_Dim].[event_id] = [event_master].[id] 
WHERE  [bag_id] = 'K5334'
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is hard to read.

Comment: By which column value(s) do you want to combine two rows into one?

Comment: The idea is to return one row with the venue_location_master.location_name for both the origin_location_id and the destination_location_id. I'm guessing this may require giving the column an alias to differentiate them?

Comment: Use common alias name for `[destination_location_id]` and  `[origin_location_id]`

Comment: Getting closer. See the amended code above. I have two columns with alias's now, but i'm still only pulling the name based on the destination_location_id join to venue_location_master.id. I'm unsure of how to get the origin_location_name for the origin_id, and the destination_location_name for the destination_id within the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join two times on the same table, if you use aliases.

Just join on the right fields, and this should do the trick.

```
SELECT 
  [bag_id],
  [created_date],
  [created_by_employee],

  --origin
  [origin_location_id],
  --use table alias to get correct origin name
  ISNULL(origin.[location_name], 'NULL') AS [origin_name],  

  --destination
  [destination_location_id],
  --use table alias to get correct destination name
  ISNULL(destination.[location_name], 'NULL') AS [destination_name],

  ISNULL([event_master].[event_name], 'NULL') AS [event_name]  
FROM [variance_cash].[dbo].[Bag_Dim] 

--join on destination, alias is... destination
LEFT JOIN [verteda_rts_v4].[dbo].[venue_location_master]  as destination
      ON [Bag_Dim].[destination_location_id] = destination.[id] 

--join  on origin, alias is... origin
LEFT JOIN [verteda_rts_v4].[dbo].[venue_location_master] as origin  
      ON [Bag_Dim].[origin_location_id] = origin.[id]  

LEFT JOIN [verteda_rts_v4].[dbo].[event_master] 
   ON [Bag_Dim].[event_id] = [event_master].[id] 
WHERE  [bag_id] = 'K5334'
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. It was the giving the join tables an alias that I couldn't get my head around!